# Can I use the `brace-init-list` to initialize a struct which contains `std::string` field?

Tags: c++

As far as I known, `std::string` is a non-POD type.
When I define a struct which contains `std::string` field.
Can I still use the `brace-init-list` to initialize the struct?
The code bellow works. Compiler gives me no warning. Am I missing something?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    struct Book
    {
        int id;
        std::string title;
    };

    Book book = {42, "hello, world"};
    printf("%d:%s\n", book.id, book.title.c_str());
}
```

---

```
$ g++ --version
g++ (GCC) 4.1.2 20070925 (Red Hat 4.1.2-33)
$ g++ -Wall -std=c++98 main.cpp -lstdc++
$ ./a.out
42:hello, world
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Book` type is an aggregate, hence using the aggregate initialization syntax is perfectly fine. Whether or not the members themselves are PODs or aggregates does not matter at all.

- [Related FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4178175/)

Comment: `"Whether or not the members themselves are PODs or aggregates does not matter at all."`. It does matter in C++03.

Comment: `An aggregate is an array or a class (clause 9) with no user-declared constructors (12.1), no private or protected non-static data members (clause 11), no base classes (clause 10), and no virtual functions (10.3).` Hence, the Book type *is* an aggregate.